# ERROR: Named volume "dir-sites:/home/sites/:rw" is used in service "my-httpd" but no declaration was found in the volumes section

Tags: docker-compose, window

I practice Docker compose on Environments:
-Window 10.
-My host folder: E:\learnt_docker\mycode

In "mycode" folder have:
 1. db folder
 2. php folder
 2.1. Dockerfile
 3. sites folder
 3.1. site1 folder
 4. docker-compose.yml
 5. httpd.conf
 6. my.cnf (This file from mysql )

I wanted to create docker compose. In file include PHP, HTTPD and MySQL

Below is the single compose file:

```
version: "3"

#NETWORK
networks: 
    my-network:
        driver: bridge

#VOLUMES
volumes: 
    dir-site:
        driver_opts: 
            device: /mycode/sites/
            o: bind        
services: 
    # Container PHP
    my-php:
        container_name: php-product
        build: 
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            context: ./php/
        hostname: php
        restart: always
        networks: 
            - my-network
        volumes: 
            - dir-site:/home/sites/
    # Container HTTPD
    my-httpd:
        container_name: c-httpd01
        image: "httpd:latest"
        hostname: httpd
        restart: always
        networks: 
            - my-network
        volumes: 
            - dir-sites:/home/sites/
            - ./httpd.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
        ports: 
            - "9999:80" # http://localhost:9999
            - "443:443"
    # Container MySQL
    my-mysql:
        container_name: mysql-product
        image: "mysql:latest"
        hostname: mysql
        restart: always
        networks: 
            - my-network
        volumes: 
            - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
            - ./my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
        environment: 
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123
            - MYSQL_DATABAS=db_site
            - MYSQL_USER=siteuser
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=sitepass
```

It display error when I run and I don't know why

Comment: Your top-level `volumes:` section declares `dir-site`, but when you reference it you use `dir-sites` (with an "s" on the end).  The error is just that these don't match.

Comment: Thank for your help

Answer (score 0):

In your top-level volumes section you have declared dir-site, but when you trying to reference it you are using dir-sites.

That's why you are getting ERROR as declaration not found in volume section.